# jmeter - How to tell forEach to loop based on the two created variables

Tags: jmeter

Having huge json which is got like

```
[
  "Zurich - Wil",
  "Salzburg - Dac 1904 Dunajska Streda",
  "Sturm Graz - FC Juniors OO",
  "Grasshopper  - Schaffhausen",
  "Liefering - Ried",
  "Grazer Athletiksport Klub - TUS Bad Gleichenberg",
  "Shamrock Rovers - Drogheda United FC",
  "Waterford United FC - Saint Patrick's Athletic FC",
  "Dundalk - Derry City ",
  "Finn Harps FC - Longford Town",
  "Flora Tallinn - Nomme Kalju",
  "Jalgpallikool Tammeka - Paide Linnameeskond",
  "Viljandi JK Tulevik - Parnu JK Vaprus",
  "Al Masry Club - El-Entag El-Harby",
  "El Gouna - Ceramica Cleopatra",
  "Ghazl El Mahallah - Al Ittihad Al Sakandary",
  "Aswan - Wadi Degla",
  "Apr FC - Rutsiro FC",
  "AS Kigali - Police FC Rwanda",
  "Rayon Sports FC - Espoir FC",
  "AS Muhanga - Gasogi United",
  "Sunrise - Musanze"
]
```

From which I create two sets of variables

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    vars.put("opponentA" + i, (vars.get("ID1_" + i)).split(" - ")[0]);
    vars.put("opponentB" + i, (vars.get("ID1_" + i)).split(" - ")[1]);
    
    //log.warn(vars.get("opponentA" + i));
    //log.warn(vars.get("opponentB" + i));
}
```

opponentA, opponentB

How to tell forEach controller to loop based on the combination of opponentA && opponentB?
In other words to loop based on every single opponent that is present in the above JSON?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your ForEach Controller configuration to look like:

   [image]
2. Once done you will be able to refer:

   - `opponentA` as `${opponentA}`
   - `opponentB` as `${__V(opponentB${__intSum(${__jm__ForEach Controller__idx},1,)},)}`

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [__intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum)
- [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V)
- [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)

Comment: but is this way forEach loop is looping based on the matches. I need to loop based on the opponents.

ex: Zurich, Wil -> 2 times